# If matrix A commutes with B, and B commutes with C, and B is non invertible, is it true that A commutes with C?

Tags: matrices

Original question asked:

If matrix $A$ commutes with $B$, and $B$ commutes with $C$, then does matrix $A$ commute with $C$?

This can easily be disproven by taking $B = I$ and looking at some matrices $A$ and $C$ that doesn't satisfy the condition.

However, I thought: if $B$ is given to be non-invertible, is the case true?

If so, why? If not, can you provide an example?

Also, if not, are there any stronger conditions that would make the case true (for example, $A$ and $C$ has to be both non-invertible)?

Comment: What if $B$ is the $0$ matrix?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. That answers my first question. Now my second question: what if $B$ is given to be non-invertible and nonzero?

Comment: You could ask $B$ to not have repeated eigenvalues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider the following counterexample over any ring with singular matrices first, where $AB=BA=BC=CB=AC=0\ne CA$:
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&0&1\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0},\ B=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&0&0},\ C=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\ 1&0&0\\ 0&0&0}.
$$
Now you may add the identity matrix $I$ to $A,B$ or $C$ to make them nonsingular.